# Solve for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, where $f(x,y,u,v)$ using implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, vector-analysis

I have pasted the problem and part of the solution below.  This question is from Marsdens vector calculus in the section on the implicit function theorem.  They did the first part by computing the determinant where each row of the matric contained in the component functions, and each column computed the partial derivative of that component function, first with respect to $u$ then with $v$.

**My Question**

To find $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ why did they implicitly differentiate each component function at $x$, $u$, and $v$?  Differentiating at $x$ then implictly differentiating $u$ with respect to $x$, is what I would've done, so I'm not sure why they also implicity differentiated $v$ with respect to $x$?

Thanks

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: Please start formatting your entire posts in mathjax.  You clearly know how to use it.  Uploaded images may not last; and when there is no added value in adding an image (e.g., in a geometry problem), you should be using strictly mathjax.  I know this has been told to you countless times now.

Comment: Is there something I can do to make sure the images last?  When I paste an image it's because formatting will take more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that both $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $y$

Here $x$ and $y$ are independent variables while $u$ and $v$ are dependent variables.

When you differentiate the equation involving both $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$ we have to differentiate each and every term.

For example from $$ u+v=2x+y$$ we get $$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac {\partial v}{\partial x} =2$$

Even though we are only interested in $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$ we still have to count   $\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$ in the equation.